# Regex Java - Opennms HTTP Collector

Tags: java, http, opennms

**Update: The log reports:**

```
no attributes defined by the response: <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://foo.com/foo1">

        CSG - Client:DRS - Site:foo1 Gdns - August 13 2015 06:28 AM
        <i style="display:none">opennms9929opennms</i>
    </a>
```

**It seems that my regex in the XML is incorrect. Please could anyone provide the correct regex for my issue? thanks.**

I have been trying to setting up an HTTP Collector using OpenNMS to periodically collecting a number from a website, and the raw HTML code would be something like:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML> 
............
<i style="display:none" >opennms781opennms</i>
............
</body>
</html>
```

The goal is to collect the number in between `opennms(number)opennms` using regex.

I have edited the required XML files as explained in [OpenNMS HTTP Collector Wiki](http://www.opennms.org/wiki/HTTP_Collector), and OpenNMS was able to pull raw HTML data and record them in the log, however I am still getting the following warnings/errors:

```
2015-08-13 14:18:39,946 WARN  [Collectd-Thread-49-of-50] o.o.n.c.HttpCollector: doCollection: More than 1 Content-Language headers received. Ignoring them!
2015-08-13 14:18:39,946 WARN  [Collectd-Thread-49-of-50] o.o.n.c.HttpCollector: doCollection: no attributes defined by the response: <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://foo.com/foo1">

    CSG - Client:DRS - Site:foo1 Gdns - August 13 2015 06:28 AM
    <i style="display:none">opennms9929opennms</i>
</a>
2015-08-12 12:08:14,771 WARN  [Collectd-Thread-10-of-50] o.o.n.c.HttpCollector: collect: http collection failed
org.opennms.netmgt.collectd.HttpCollector$HttpCollectorException: Unexpected exception caught during HTTP collection
    at org.opennms.netmgt.collectd.HttpCollector.doCollection(HttpCollector.java:307) ~[opennms-services-16.0.2.jar:?]
    at org.opennms.netmgt.collectd.HttpCollector.access$100(HttpCollector.java:107) ~[opennms-services-16.0.2.jar:?]
    at org.opennms.netmgt.collectd.HttpCollector$HttpCollectionSet.collect(HttpCollector.java:179) [opennms-services-16.0.2.jar:?]
    at org.opennms.netmgt.collectd.HttpCollector.collect(HttpCollector.java:139) [opennms-services-16.0.2.jar:?]
    at org.opennms.netmgt.collectd.CollectionSpecification.collect(CollectionSpecification.java:274) [opennms-services-16.0.2.jar:?]
    at org.opennms.netmgt.collectd.CollectableService.doCollection(CollectableService.java:388) [opennms-services-16.0.2.jar:?]
    at org.opennms.netmgt.collectd.CollectableService.doRun(CollectableService.java:322) [opennms-services-16.0.2.jar:?]
    at org.opennms.netmgt.collectd.CollectableService.access$000(CollectableService.java:70) [opennms-services-16.0.2.jar:?]
    at org.opennms.netmgt.collectd.CollectableService$1.run(CollectableService.java:300) [opennms-services-16.0.2.jar:?]
    at org.opennms.core.logging.Logging.withPrefix(Logging.java:66) [org.opennms.core.logging-16.0.2.jar:?]
    at org.opennms.netmgt.collectd.CollectableService.run(CollectableService.java:296) [opennms-services-16.0.2.jar:?]
    at org.opennms.netmgt.scheduler.LegacyScheduler$1.run(LegacyScheduler.java:209) [opennms-services-16.0.2.jar:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [?:1.8.0_51]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [?:1.8.0_51]
    at org.opennms.core.concurrent.LogPreservingThreadFactory$3.run(LogPreservingThreadFactory.java:124) [opennms-util-16.0.2.jar:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_51]
2015-08-12 12:08:14,771 WARN  [Collectd-Thread-10-of-50] o.o.n.c.CollectableService: run: failed collection for 63/(foo's IP)/HttpSecCount/foo1
2015-08-12 12:08:14,771 ERROR [Collectd-Thread-10-of-50] o.o.n.c.CollectableService: Collection failed for an unknown reason (code 2.  Please review previous logs for this thread for details.  You can also open up an enhancement bug report (include your logs) to request that failure messages are logged for this type of error.
org.opennms.netmgt.collectd.CollectionFailed: Collection failed for an unknown reason (code 2.  Please review previous logs for this thread for details.  You can also open up an enhancement bug report (include your logs) to request that failure messages are logged for this type of error.
    at org.opennms.netmgt.collectd.CollectableService.doCollection(CollectableService.java:413) ~[opennms-services-16.0.2.jar:?]
    at org.opennms.netmgt.collectd.CollectableService.doRun(CollectableService.java:322) [opennms-services-16.0.2.jar:?]
    at org.opennms.netmgt.collectd.CollectableService.access$000(CollectableService.java:70) [opennms-services-16.0.2.jar:?]
    at org.opennms.netmgt.collectd.CollectableService$1.run(CollectableService.java:300) [opennms-services-16.0.2.jar:?]
    at org.opennms.core.logging.Logging.withPrefix(Logging.java:66) [org.opennms.core.logging-16.0.2.jar:?]
    at org.opennms.netmgt.collectd.CollectableService.run(CollectableService.java:296) [opennms-services-16.0.2.jar:?]
    at org.opennms.netmgt.scheduler.LegacyScheduler$1.run(LegacyScheduler.java:209) [opennms-services-16.0.2.jar:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [?:1.8.0_51]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [?:1.8.0_51]
    at org.opennms.core.concurrent.LogPreservingThreadFactory$3.run(LogPreservingThreadFactory.java:124) [opennms-util-16.0.2.jar:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_51]
```

I am wondering if anyone knows what might have caused this issue?

**http-datacollection-config.xml**:

```
<http-collection name="sec-count">
    <rrd step="900">
      <rra>RRA:AVERAGE:0.5:1:2016</rra>
      <rra>RRA:AVERAGE:0.5:12:1488</rra>
      <rra>RRA:AVERAGE:0.5:288:366</rra>
      <rra>RRA:MAX:0.5:288:366</rra>
      <rra>RRA:MIN:0.5:288:366</rra>
    </rrd>
    <uris>
      <uri name="foo">
        <url path="/foo1/index.php"
         host="www.foo.com"
             user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; rv:36.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/36.0" 
             matches="(?!opennms)(\d+)(?=opennms)" response-range="100-399" >
        </url>
        <attributes>
          <attrib alias="secondCount" match-group="1" type="gauge"/>
        </attributes>
      </uri>
    </uris>
  </http-collection>
```

**collectd-configuration.xml**:
Under the package "Example1"

```
<service name="HttpSecCount" interval="900000" user-defined="false" status="on">
            <parameter key="collection" value="sec-count"/>
        </service>
<collector service="HttpSecCount" class-name="org.opennms.netmgt.collectd.HttpCollector"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

`(?!opennms)(\d+)(?=opennms)` is not the regex you're looking for:

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Try with the following one instead:

```
(?<=opennms)(\d+)(?=opennms)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

*Visualizations by [Debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/)*

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your advise. I have applied the changes you suggested and now I get the following error:   The value of attribute "matches" associated with an element type "url" must not contain the '<' character.

Answer (score 0):

The error was caused by the incorrect regular expression, and this has been fixed using a Java Regex [verification tool](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~matuszek/General/RegexTester/regex-tester.html) provided in the OpenNMS wiki.